# How to use EfficientNet-Lite4 with tensorflow Lite

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, image-classification, efficientnet

I try to use EfficientNet-Lite4 on google colab with tensorflow Lite but i have an error `name 'efficienetnet_lite4_spec' is not defined` What should I do? Or does it only work with EfficientNet-Lite0?
[image]

Comment: change `efficienetnet_lite4_spec`  to `efficientnet_lite4_spec`.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen thank you so much, I have tried following your suggestion by changing to `model_spec = model_spec.get('efficientnet_lite4')` and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments

> Code change from
>
> ```
> model = image_classifier.create(train_data, model_spec=efficienetnet_lite4_spec,validation_data=validation_data,epochs=300)
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> model = image_classifier.create(train_data, model_spec=model_spec.get('efficientnet_lite4'),validation_data=validation_data,epochs=300)
> ```
>
> has resolved the issue (paraphrased from RJ Adriaansen & zeewa42)